# Using Clang as an API

Tags: clang, llvm, code-generation

I don't know much about Clang APIs, so forgive the silly question.

If I am building a compiler for a language which have the same or similar features to C++, can I use Clang APIs to take responsibility for the code generation for me? For example, say I implemented a parser to parse the following code:

```
def class Adder
   def func Add(x as int, y as int) as int
     return x + y
```

Now say I parsed this code and I have the AST for it, I can use Clang APIs to generate the code for this class for me?

I know I can use LLVM APIs, and I have done so, but LLVM as relatively low level and it doesn't support OOP, so I would have to support them myself, which is not an easy task at all. So I am wondering whether there is anyway to employ Clang to do that job for me. If yes, I would be grateful if you can provide me with examples and links.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no.

A longer answer is that, Clang is just a compiler from C++ (and C and ObjC) to LLVM IR, going via the AST. Its external APIs all relate to compiling and analyzing C++.

Once you parse a language like your sample to an AST, what you need is precisely the LLVM APIs to construct LLVM IR. [The LLVM tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html) is the perfect start.

Now, it's not that Clang is useless for you. Clang compiles C++ to LLVM IR. So it has code for handling OOP constructs and all other C++ constructs that are higher-level than LLVM IR. You can definitely learn from what it's doing by reading its code, but AFAIK none of this is really a public API.

Comment: So there is no way to use Clang constructs directly? I mean rather than using LLVM APIs directly as in the tutorial you provided, can I not use the constructs of Clang?!

Comment: @Rafid: again, Clang is a C++ compiler. You want to compile some custom language. How do you expect Clang to provide you with APIs for that task?

Comment: No, sorry if I didn't make it clear. I am not expeting Clang to provide APIs for understanding my language. I am just wondering whether it is possible to use its "C++" constructs to make the code generation easier for me. Let me try to clarify this more. Say I want to implement a new C++ compiler (obviously this is a trivial example, because there are just too many C++ compilers) and I have implemented the syntax analyzer. Can I connect this to Clang so that it generates the code for me?

Comment: @Rafid: no, this isn't exposed publicly. Clang does this in the Sema layer, which gets called directly from the parser

Comment: Thanks Eli Bendersky.